# Can ALL 256 byte values be written to a text file without any issues?

Tags: c++, file, byte, ascii, eof

Can writing all (0-255) byte values to a text file cause any errors?
Since byte '0' is EOF, does that mean my file can contain exactly one EOF character and everything after is ignored?

> Edit: Files can contain ANY byte value (0-255) and they can repeat as many times as you want.

I feel dumb now.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "errors". If you try to interpret that file as some file type, it probably won't work. But there is nothing wrong from a C++ point of view about having any of those bytes in a file. Why do you think a `0` byte means EOF? Because it is used to indicate the end of a C-string? Those are not the same thing at all.

Comment: Ok, but what is then EOF, if we use up all bytes, how will file end be labeled. I might be missing sometinhg.

Comment: Nope. I execute a program that writes all 0-255 bytes to some file almost every day. This program is called a "C++ compiler".

Comment: Does that mean I can enter any combination of one's and zero's to a file and I will not break anything?

Comment: Absolutely. You can write anything into a file. As many ones and zeroes as your hard drive will hold. Now, doing it correctly, and correctly reading it back, that would be a different story...

Comment: `EOF` is used as a return value for functions that read, such as `scanf`, but that value isn't read from the file.

Comment: Any old garbage can be written into, and later rad from, a disk file.  Windows ME was stored as disk files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a reason that (on some systems) text-files are distinguished from "binary" files.

As far as I'm aware there is no system where writing any byte to a file will cause a direct problem, but writing or reading "any byte" as a text-file may lead to a number of problems:

- Some bytes may get translated to another byte, or more than one byte - e.g. in DOS and Windows, a newline when written (`'\n'` or byte 10 (0x0a)) will become `"\r\n"`). And vice versa, reading that sequence will be just one character.
- Some byte or combination of bytes, when read, can be seen as "end of file". In Windows, that is CTRL-Z. The origin of this system of marking the end of file with a special character is that some operating systems would have a "number of blocks" for the file-size, rather than storing the actual size in the meta-data for the file. This meant that a file's size would be rounded up to the nearest block - e.g. 512 bytes, and if you want a file that is 108 bytes long, you'd write 108 bytes of text and then a CTRL-Z [or whatever that system uses] to mark that "the rest of this block is not part of the text".

Binary files can contain absolutely any byte, and if the bytes are transmitted over some sort of link (e.g. network) that can't cope with absolutely any combination of bytes, it is up to the layers of that network link to convert it to something that works, and then convert it back again.